# Are there any benefits beyond getting new features to upgrade the targeted framework in a .NET project

Tags: c#, .net

I'm working on updated the dependencies of a Nuget project and was considering also updating the framework it targets. 
My question, if there are no features you need from the new framework, will there be any other benefits (performance benefits) from doing an upgrade. I have read that running a .NET 3.5 assembly in .NET 4.5 Host can gain performance improvements. But I've seen nothing to suggest that compiling for a later version of the framework will help.

Comment: Target the .NET version that you *need* to write your library.  The programmer that uses your library needs to target a version that is at least as high as yours.  Which does of course mean that the higher the version you target, the less like another programmer can use it.  Getting perf improvements by intentionally targeting a lesser version is nonsense.

Comment: Ideally your library should support any framework. 4.5 breaking change is no more Windows XP support (4.0 is the last), so switching from 3.5 to 4.5 means loosing any potential user who is targeting Windows XP. Much better options is to have branches (not sure how this can be done with nuget), this way using newest (latest) framework version is a guarantee what your library will stay actual, updated and improved, while keeping other older framework branches.

Comment: Aside from features, and the risk of losing compatibility, there are few other factors to consider when upgrading target frameworks. You can sometimes get performance improvements by upgrading to a later version of the *compiler* that can generate better IL, though, even if you don't change your target framework version.

Comment: Thank Hans, that is probably the correct approach to take. Sinatr, the way I was planning to do this was have the build process spit out multiple builds and target them against the different framework versions I wanted to support. Nuget then allows you have different copies of the same assembly to target different frameworks in different folders.

Answer (score 0):

It might depend on what classes and libraries you're currently using in your project. Sometimes newer framework versions have code improvements that can provide various performance improvements. Also, if you come from .NET 3.5, you're also upgrading the CLR to 4.0.

In the other hand, when you target to a new framework version you need to check what has been considered *obsolete* and *deprecated*, because maybe you're looking for performance gains and finally your application/service gets broken...

In summary, there's no general performance gain, it depends on your framework usage.

Answer (score 0):

If you check here 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171868(v=vs.100).aspx
 you will see a list of improvements, and see if anything is relevant to you, like enumerating files or making interop operations for example. About more general improvements, the garbage collector was changed. Microsoft claims it leads to better performance, and there is a chance they are right. I would advise you to run some tests and check performance, I think its a lot simpler than to go through all the code and all of Microsoft's related documents and believe these documents. There is also the issue of what might brake when you change target version, and i think it should have some weight in the decision. is a month of work worth 1ms performance improvement? etc.